# How to use mongoexport with a dynamic variable for date on windows batch file?

Tags: mongodb, windows, export, command-line

Here is my working script:

> mongoexport --db db1 --collection Transaction --out C:\Users\Admin\transactionstats.json --query="{"PaymentDate":{"$gte":{"$date":"2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"},"$lte":{"$date":"2022-01-31T23:59:59.999Z"}},"TransactionStatus":1}"

my issue is that I want to automate this to execute every 1st of the month. if I run it on Feb 1, 2023, the date that should be extracted would be between Jan 1, 2023 - Jan 31, 2023

Comment: I think doing this purely in BATCH would result in rather much code. Better take a script language of your choice, generate the command dynamically and execute it. Most scripting languages have decent support for date/time functions and I guess all of them can make system calls to run `mongoexport`.